# tailwind css svg icon text center is not working

Tags: svg, tailwind-css

tailwind CSS SVG icon text center is not working, also tried with CSS

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.1.2/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="tab" calss="bg-gray-500">
  <a href="#" class="bg-gray-100 w-full focus:text-teal-500 hover:text-teal-500 justify-center inline-block text-center pt-2 pb-1">

    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
  <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M3 12l2-2m0 0l7-7 7   7M5 10v10a1 1 0 001 1h3m10-11l2 2m-2-2v10a1 1 0 01-1 1h-3m-6 0a1 1 0 001-1v-4a1 1 0 011-1h2a1 1 0 011 1v4a1 1 0 001 1m-6 0h6" />
  </svg>

    <span class="block text-xs">Home</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,

###### Example 1

```
<div id="tab" class="bg-gray-100 w-full focus:text-teal-500 hover:text-teal-500 flex py-1 justify-center">
  <a href="#">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6 mx-auto" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
      <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M3 12l2-2m0 0l7-7 7   7M5 10v10a1 1 0 001 1h3m10-11l2 2m-2-2v10a1 1 0 01-1 1h-3m-6 0a1 1 0 001-1v-4a1 1 0 011-1h2a1 1 0 011 1v4a1 1 0 001 1m-6 0h6" />
    </svg>
    <span class="block text-xs">Home</span>
  </a>
</div>

<br />
```

###### Example 2

```
<div class="flex w-full justify-center">
  <div id="tab" class="bg-gray-100 w-10 h-10 focus:text-teal-500 hover:text-teal-500 flex py-1 justify-center">
    <a href="#">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6 mx-auto" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M3 12l2-2m0 0l7-7 7   7M5 10v10a1 1 0 001 1h3m10-11l2 2m-2-2v10a1 1 0 01-1 1h-3m-6 0a1 1 0 001-1v-4a1 1 0 011-1h2a1 1 0 011 1v4a1 1 0 001 1m-6 0h6" />
      </svg>
      <span class="block text-xs">Home</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

***Tailwind Playground*** [sample](https://play.tailwindcss.com/q1K9CDSNVM)

Comment: The second example is working fine, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want? Then you need to add `items-center` and `flex` instead of `inline-block` for container

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.1.2/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="tab" calss="bg-gray-500">
  <a href="#" class="bg-gray-100 w-full focus:text-teal-500 hover:text-teal-500 justify-center items-center flex text-center pt-2 pb-1">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
      <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M3 12l2-2m0 0l7-7 7   7M5 10v10a1 1 0 001 1h3m10-11l2 2m-2-2v10a1 1 0 01-1 1h-3m-6 0a1 1 0 001-1v-4a1 1 0 011-1h2a1 1 0 011 1v4a1 1 0 001 1m-6 0h6" />
    </svg>

    <span class="block text-xs">Home</span>
  </a>
</div>
```